# How can one do a pixel by pixel comparison of an image created by cairo and an image loaded from a file

Tags: image, diff, cairo, nim-lang

I have some code in nim that creates a picture using Cairo (https://github.com/nim-lang/cairo).  I would like to compare that picture to another using diffimg (https://github.com/SolitudeSF/diffimg, https://github.com/SolitudeSF/imageman).

But there does not seem to be a standard in memory image type.  Is there any way to do this that does not involve saving the image to a file first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the most easy way is surprisingly to implement yourself the `diffimg` algorithm. Looking at the source of `diffimg` shows the comparison algoritm is [about 20 lines of code](https://github.com/SolitudeSF/diffimg/blob/master/src/diffimg.nim#L3-L19):

```
func absDiff[T: ColorComponent](a, b: T): T {.inline.} =
  if a > b:
    a - b
  else:
    b - a

func getDiffRatio*[T: Color](a, b: Image[T]): float =
  for p in 0..a.data.high:
    for c in 0..T.high:
      result += absDiff(a[p][c], b[p][c]).float
  result / (T.maxComponentValue.float * a.data.len.float * T.len.float)

func genDiffImage*[T: Color](a, b: Image[T]): Image[T] =
  result = initImage[T](a.w, a.h)
  for p in 0..result.data.high:
    for c in 0..T.high:
      result[p][c] = absDiff(a[p][c], b[p][c])
```

The actual trouble of loading the image is left to `imageman`, but all in all it seems to substract pixel component values between the two images and create some kind of average/ratio. Since the cairo library seems to generate its own, possibly incompatible, memory layout for images, most likely you want to ignore `imageman` and load the image you want to compare to yourself into a cairo memory buffer, then replicate the diffing algorithm iterating through the pixels of each caro image. Or maybe convert the cairo buffer to an `imageman` buffer and let the `diffimg` implementation do its magic.

Comment: I thought I might have to do something like that.  I was hoping that someone would have a ready made function that would give me the Cairo image in a format that was in a format defined as a Nim type.  Thanks anyway.